# How to make a histogram of showing number of items for on the x axis with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that finds all of the anagrams for each word in a scrabble dictionary. I would like to make a histogram with matplotlib to show the size of the anagrams on the x axis, but I don't really know where to start. I believe I need to convert the strings values to integers but I'm not sure how to covert the dictionary string values to integers.

Thanks!

```
# import libraries
import urllib2
from collections import defaultdict

#function for inputing words
def load_dictionary(word_dictionary):
    for word in word_dictionary:
        yield word.strip()

#function for making anagrams
def make_anagrams(source):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in source:
        key = "".join(sorted(word))
        d[key].append(word)
    return d

#function for printing anagrams
def print_anagrams(word_input):
    count=0
    n=0
    k=''
    d = make_anagrams(word_input)
    for key, anagrams in d.iteritems():
        if len(anagrams) > 1:
            count+= 1
            if n < len(anagrams):
                n=len(anagrams) 
                k=key
    print 'The number of unique anagrams is: %d:' % count
    print 'The largest group of anagrams for a word is: %d; and the original word is: %s' % ( n , k)
    print 'The anagrams for the largest anagram word is: %s ' % d[k]


#input dictionary from puzzlers.org               
word_dictionary = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/ospd.txt')
word_input = load_dictionary(word_dictionary)
#print answer
print_anagrams(word_input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Counter from collection module. Here is the modified version of your code to draw histogram:

```
# import libraries    
import urllib2    
from collections import defaultdict    
from collections import Counter    
from matplotlib import pylab as plt    

#function for inputing words    
def load_dictionary(word_dictionary):    
    for word in word_dictionary:    
        yield word.strip()    

#function for making anagrams    
def make_anagrams(source):    
    d = defaultdict(list)    
    for word in source:    
        key = "".join(sorted(word))    
        d[key].append(word)    
    return d    

#function for printing anagrams    
def print_anagrams(word_input):    
    count=0    
    n=0    
    k=''    
    d = make_anagrams(word_input)    
    anagramLens =Counter()    
    for key, anagrams in d.iteritems():    
        anagramLens[len(anagrams)] += 1    
        if len(anagrams) > 1:    
            count+= 1    
            if n < len(anagrams):    
                n=len(anagrams)    
                k=key    
    print 'The number of unique anagrams is: %d:' % count    
    print 'The largest group of anagrams for a word is: %d; and the original word is: %s' % ( n , k)    
    print 'The anagrams for the largest anagram word is: %s ' % d[k]    
    #print list(anagramLens.elements())    
    plt.figure()    
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(list(anagramLens.elements()), histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)    
    plt.show()    
#input dictionary from puzzlers.org                   
word_dictionary = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/ospd.txt')    
word_input = load_dictionary(word_dictionary)    
#print answer    
print_anagrams(word_input)
```